# Magento 2 : Fetch system.xml group id in source model

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-config, system-configuration, source-model

In Magento 2, I want to fetch group id from system.xml in my custom sourceModel

[image]

But I am unable to find a solution online.

Please do let me know if it's possible or not.

I know there's an alternate solution to create 2 separate source Models for this purpose but I want to use only one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The config fields default html are created from function **getElementHtml** defined the class

> Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement

The input field name contains the section, group and field name as well. You can make use of function **getName** defined in the above class to get the group name.

For example in my source model class

```
class Education extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $name = $element->getName();
        // result will be => groups[group_name][fields][field_name]
        //do your logic
        return $element->getElementHtml();
    }
}
```